# Why can't I catch this exception?

Tags: c++

I want to create a number of exception types which derive from std::runtime_error and I want them to have stringstream type functionality.  I've therefore created an exception class which composes a `std::stringstream` and which derives from `std::runtime_error`:

```
template<typename T>
class error_stream : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
      error_stream() :
      std::runtime_error(""), ss(std::make_shared<std::basic_stringstream<T>> ())
      {
      }

      ~error_stream() throw()
      {
      }

      template <typename T>
      error_stream & operator << (const T & t)
      {
          *ss << t;
          return *this;
      }

      virtual const char * what() const throw()
      {
          get_str(s_, ss->str());
          return s_.c_str();
      }

protected:

    template <typename T>
    void get_str(std::basic_string<char> & s_, const std::basic_string<T> & str) const
    {
        s_ = str;
    }

    template<>
    void get_str(std::basic_string<char> & s_, const std::basic_string<wchar_t> & str) const
    {
        std::basic_string<char> ret(str.begin(), str.end());
        s_ = ret;
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<std::basic_stringstream<T>> ss;
    mutable std::basic_string<char> s_;
};
```

And I've created a more specific exception type which in turn derives from this `error_stream` exception:

```
template<typename T>
class w32file_exception : public w32utils::error_stream<T> 
{
public:
    w32file_exception() : error_stream<T>() {}
};
```

However, I've encountered something I don't understand here, because when I throw a `w32file_exception` I actually can only catch it as it's parent `error_stream`.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
    try
    {
        throw w32file_exception<char>() << "test";
    }
    catch ( w32file_exception<char> & e )
    {
        ASSERT_PASSED;
    }
    catch ( error_stream<char> & e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  // Why do I end up here?
    }
```

Comment: I don't know your use case of the `operator<<` so I don't know if this helps - but I just wanted to mention [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) and in particular the [Transporting of Arbitrary Data to the Catch Site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_transporting_data.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What exactly does your `throw` look like? Are you using your `operator<<` before calling throw, like this:

```
throw w32file_exception<T>() << "fooobar";
```

Then the answer is, that your `operator<<` returns an `error_stream` and no `w32file_exception` and so the type of the thrown exception is `error_stream`.

You could solve this problem this way:

```
template<typename T, typename DERIVED>
    class error_stream : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename U>
        DERIVED & operator << (const T & t)
    {
        *ss << t;
        return static_cast<DERIVED&>(*this);
    }
    // ...
};
```

But then you loose the ability to catch every `error_stream` exception because it is a new Type for every `DERIVED` type.

Comment: A couple of issues (I tried this out myself but you beat me to the answer): 1. `catch ( error_stream<char> & e )` needs an extra parameter (but this might be because I was using DevStudio 2005) and 2. I didn't `static_cast` but rather had a `virtual D &GetThis () = 0;` which returned the `this` pointer of the derived type, defined in the derived type as `virtual w32file_exception <T> &GetThis () { return *this; }`

Comment: @Skizz 1. yes - didn't think about this - you could default the second template parameter to `error_stream`. 2. should make no real difference. i think both solutions work

Comment: @FlorianSowade Your answer #1 to Skizzes question doesn't quite work, you can't default the template parameter to `error_stream` since that would be an incomplete type.  Neither can you default it to `error_stream<T, error_stream<T>>` since this is a recursive declaration and won't compile.  This means it's not actually possible to catch the base type using this mechanism.